# Settings to access printer 'PrinterName' are not valid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I'm try to access network printer via MVC web application.

this is code...

```
void Main(){
    PrintDocument printDoc = new PrintDocument();
    printDoc.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = @"SP";
    printDoc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(printImg_PrintPage);
    printDoc.Print(); // [ERROR:Settings to access printer 'PrinterName' are not valid ]
}

void printImg_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e) {
    Point ulCorner = new Point(10, 0);
    var photo = TheArtOfDev.HtmlRenderer.WinForms.HtmlRender.RenderToImage(html);
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(photo, ulCorner);
    photo.Dispose();
}
```

We have all user access to printer.
also set registry level configurations.

While publish on IIS We get error as below:
Settings to access printer 'SP' are not valid.

Description: 
An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details:

> System.Drawing.Printing.InvalidPrinterException: Settings to access printer 'SP' are not valid.

Comment: _"We have all user access to printer"_ - does that include the application pool user used by IIS for your app?

Comment: We have set Application pool identity  to localsystem

Comment: localsystem ["acts as the computer on the network"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/localsystem-account) rather than as a 'user'

Comment: Please suggest what we are missing

Comment: As those docs say _"A service that runs in the context of the LocalSystem account inherits the security context of the SCM. The user SID is created from the SECURITY_LOCAL_SYSTEM_RID value. **The account is not associated with any logged-on user account**."_ and then _"Most services do not need such a high privilege level. If your service does not need these privileges, and it is not an interactive service, consider using the LocalService account or the NetworkService account."_ - or you can create a specific user with the required permissions required and run the app under that identity.